# How can I use the WhatsApp Share Button to share Images?

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, share, whatsapp

WhatsApp provides a share button which can be implemented on a html page for iOs devices like this:

```
<a href="whatsapp://send?text=Text">Text</a>
```

**Is it possible to send images with this share link somehow?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No this is not possible, whatsapp does not have any public API you can use.

Answer (score 1):

No, and Facebook's recent acquisition of Whatsapp makes this possible option surely soon deprecated (it was already on test for iOS devices)