# Share an image from my website on Whatsapp

Tags: javascript, html, whatsapp

My website is used mainly from mobiles and I want to allow my users to click a "Share on Whatsapp" button which will open Whatsapp on their device with an image ready to be sent. 
I know how to share text, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21935149/sharing-link-on-whatsapp-from-mobile-website-not-application-for-android), but I haven't found anything about image sharing.

Comment: According to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22461558/how-can-i-use-the-whatsapp-share-button-to-share-images) question this is not possible

Comment: Thank you. hope whatsapp will change that...

Comment: Any updates ? I have same requirement @DMEM

Comment: @Keyur Shah As far as I know this is still impossible.